# adjuntar Link Wetransfer con ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, formularios

Estoy haciendo un formulario con reactjs y el paquete de NPM emailjs, necesito adjuntar al formulario un enlace para subir archivos a `wetransfer` y que el mail mande un link para poder descargar esos archivos.
Por lo que he investigado la API de wetrasfer esta deprecada y no se como afrontar el problema.

¿Alguién me puede ayudar?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Que has [intentado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Saludos

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Pues quiero mandar documentos stls y zips que pesan bastante, y resulta que la API de wetransfer no tiene servicio. Sabéis de algún sitio parecido a wetransfer con una API en funcionamiento, que sea compatible con react? Gracias